# gulp breaks when changing $breakpoints

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using JointsWP4 and its provided gulpfile. When running gulp without changing any of these:

```
$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large);
```

gulp finishes every script like it should. I can also change all the pixel values and add (and remove) breakpoints in `$breakpoint-classes`. But when I change my code to add another breakpoint, like so:

```
$breakpoints: (
  tiny: 0,
  small: 320px,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);
$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large); //notice how I haven't even put "tiny" in!
```

running gulp would abort with: `gulp(685,0x111bd8000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f983c039bec: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Is this a bug or did I forget to do something? I wouldn't want to change the pixel sizes of the existing breakpoints because that would break my whole page. Or is it intended not to change any of the existing breakpoints?

Comment: This is probably something you're going to have to report as a bug with the folks who maintain Gulp.  Try compiling the Sass directly without using Gulp to see if you get an error.  I doubt there are any errors that Sass will generate that would cause that kind of error in Gulp (note that I don't use Gulp myself).

Comment: In actual fact, I just found out what the problem may have been. See my answer below. I hoped that it would be a bug, but apparently it's something that has to be like this...for now.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, as far as I could find out, the problem isn't with adding breakpoints. The error occurs with changing the `small` breakpoint, so in fact you CAN add breakpoints to `$breakpoint`. It's just that [apparently](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/7644) you can't, because *you aren't supposed to*, change `small` to anything else than 0, or remove the `medium` breakpoint. At least, for now (Foundation 6.2).

Which is a bummer, to say the least.